# Can't disconnect line chart with [null,null] and irregular intervals in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When I include a null element in my JSON data for a Highcharts chart it royally screws up the plotting. Here is the working slightly modified Highcharts API demo for irregular time intervals with my data added in for a single series:

http://jsfiddle.net/G2fJT/

```
        series: [{
            name: 'Winter 2007-2008',
            data: [
                [1375088618000, 23.03],
                [1375088918000, 23.02],
                [1375089218000, 24.03],
                [1375089518000, 25.02],
                [1375089818000, 24.02],
                [1375090118000, 23.02],
                [1375090418000, 23.25],
                [1375090718000, 23.51],
                [1375091018000, 27.02],
                [1375091318000, 28.02],
                [1375091618000, 29.02],
                [1375091918000, 23.02],
                [1375092218000, 23.02],
                [1375092518000, 24.02],
                [1375092818000, 25.02],
                [1375093118000, 26.02],
                [1375093418000, 27.02],
                [1375093718000, 27.02],
                [1375094018000, 26.02]
            ]
        }]
```

Now if I add a null element which should cause a gap in the chart since connectNulls defaults to false, I get this:

http://jsfiddle.net/qpNCP/

```
        series: [{
            name: 'Winter 2007-2008',
            data: [
                [1375088618000, 23.03],
                [1375088918000, 23.02],
                [1375089218000, 24.03],
                [1375089518000, 25.02],
                [1375089818000, 24.02],
                [1375090118000, 23.02],
                [1375090418000, 23.25],
                [1375090718000, 23.51],
                [1375091018000, 27.02],
                [1375091318000, 28.02],
                [1375091618000, 29.02],
                [null, null],
                [1375091918000, 23.02],
                [1375092218000, 23.02],
                [1375092518000, 24.02],
                [1375092818000, 25.02],
                [1375093118000, 26.02],
                [1375093418000, 27.02],
                [1375093718000, 27.02],
                [1375094018000, 26.02]
            ]
        }]
```

Is there a way to use null to break up the chart in a way that works with irregular intervals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Try `[1375091618000, null]`.

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qpNCP/2/)**</kbd>